# Customize text stackLabels dynamically Highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I built a bar graph with Highcharts as you can see from here:
http://jsfiddle.net/v1rbz41q/3/

With the statement:

```
chartw.yAxis [0] .options.stackLabels.formatter = function () {
             return "werfdc";
         };
```

I try to change the code from the text of stackLabels, but unfortunately nothing happens.

I ask you can change it by code?
Many thanks to the answers.
dave

Comment: Change it in your options when creating the chart. Not after it has been created.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
chartw.redraw();
```

After changing the formatter with the code in your question. Here's the [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/v1rbz41q/8/)

Comment: Many thanks, Raeen Hashemi.

But I wanted to ask, you can customize every stackLabels?
I tried, but I can not ... are all the same !!

Comment: Then, you have to manage the fields already generated, through classes managed by him; or:
 [code]for (i=1; i<=$(".highcharts-stack-labels").children().length; i++) {
        if (i == 1)
            $('*:nth-child(' + i + ')', $(".highcharts-stack-labels")).find("tspan").text("Primo commento")
            else
                $('*:nth-child(' + i + ')', $(".highcharts-stack-labels")).find("tspan").text("Secondo commento")
    }[/code]
 This way I can have the texts.
Thanks for the answers.

Comment: I can't read any of your code in the comment. Please implement what you mean in your **jsfiddle** and I will take a look. And please be clear of what you want in the end. Maybe post a picture in your question or update somehow in your jsfiddle, or even try to explain in detail.

Comment: If you have a new question that doesn't relate to this post please ask another question in **StackOverflow**, and if not please edit and update your question for everyone to understand.

Comment: I got what you meant by customizing stackLabels, but you need to be specific. Which stackLabels with which properties you want different from the others? Do you want for example Serie1, Serie2,...?

Comment: I see that you have done some work: http://jsfiddle.net/v1rbz41q/13/ Is it all good?

Comment: @Dave was it so hard to comment?